# What is the optimal asymptotic behavior of this integral over the sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics

Let $k_{1},\dots, k_{d}>1$ be integers and consider the integral
$$J_{\lambda }=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}e^{-\lambda \left(x^{2k_{1}}_{1}+\dots+ x^{2k_{d}}_{d}\right)} d\sigma(x)$$
where $d\sigma$ denotes the standard surface measure on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, $d\geq 2$.

I can not figure out the asymptotic behaviour of  $I_{\lambda}$ ad $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$.

Obviously, by the dominated convergence theorem,
$I_{\lambda}\rightarrow 0$.  We can also write
$$J_{\lambda }=2\int_{\substack{
(x_{1},\dots,x_{d-1})\in\mathbb{R}^{d-1}\\ x_{1}^{2}+\dots+x_{d-1}^{2}<1}}
e^{-\lambda \left(x^{2k_{1}}_{1}+\dots+ x^{2k_{d-1}}_{d-1}\right)-\lambda\left(1-x_{1}^{2}-\dots-x_{d-1}^{2}\right)^{k_{d}}} 
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x_{1}^{2}-\dots-x_{d-1}^{2}}} dx_{1}\dots dx_{d-1}.$$
For this formula and the transformation behind it, see e.g. the attached extract from Appendix D in Grafakos's *Classical Fourier Analysis*:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNwed.png

Now, when $x_{1}^{2}+\dots+x_{d-1}^{2}<1$ there exist two positive constants $c_{1}, c_{2}$ such that
$$c_{2}
(x^{2}_{1}+\dots+ x^{2}_{d-1})^{k_{max}}\leq
x^{2k_{1}}_{1}+\dots+ x^{2k_{d-1}}_{d-1}\leq c_{1}
(x^{2}_{1}+\dots+ x^{2}_{d-1})^{k_{min}},$$
where $k_{min}=\min_{1\leq i \leq d-1}{k_{i}}$
and $k_{max}=\max_{1\leq i \leq d-1}{k_{i}}$.

Therefore, using spherical coordinates, we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}
 \frac{e^{-\lambda r^{2k_{max}}-\lambda\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{k_{d}}}}{\sqrt{1-r^{2}}} dr\gtrsim
J_{\lambda }\gtrsim\int_{0}^{1}
 \frac{e^{-\lambda r^{2k_{min}}-\lambda\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{k_{d}}}}{\sqrt{1-r^{2}}} dr.$$

And since $1-r^2\leq r^2$ iff $1/\sqrt{2}\leq r$, we deduce that $J_{\lambda}$ decays **faster** than
$$\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}
 \frac{e^{-2\lambda r^{2k_{MM}}}}{\sqrt{1-r^{2}}} dr,$$
where $k_{MM}=\max\{k_{max},k_{d}\}$ and
**slower** than
$$\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{1}
 \frac{e^{-2\lambda r^{2k_{M}}}}{\sqrt{1-r^{2}}} dr,$$
where $k_{M}=\min\{k_{min},k_{d}\}$.

It would be very helpful to find the asymptotic behaviour of either one of the last two integrals.

Comment: If $M, m>0$ are  the maximum and the minimum of $x_1^{2k1}+\cdots+x_d^{2k_d}$ on the sphere, the integral decays at least as $Ce^{-\lambda m}$ and at most as $Ce^{-\lambda M}$ but probably you need something more precise. However, the 2 1d integrals have a completely different behaviour.

Comment: Yes. I must have made some stupid mistake somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\la\lambda\renewcommand{\S}{\mathbb S}\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$Let us show that
\begin{equation*}
    J_\la=e^{-\la(m+o(1))} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
(as $\la\to\infty$), where
\begin{equation*}
    m:=\min_{x\in\S^{d-1}}s(x),\quad s(x):=\sum_1^d x_j^{2k_j}  
\end{equation*}
for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)$.

Indeed, take any real $h>0$. Note that $m=s(y)$ for some $y\in\S^{d-1}$. Since the function $s$ is continuous, there is a neighborhood $N_h$ of $y$ on $\S^{d-1}$ such that $s\le m+h$ on $N_h$. Also, $c_h:=\si(N_h)>0$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    J_\la\ge\int_{N_h}e^{-\la s(x)}\si(dx)
\ge e^{-\la(m+h)}\,c_h=e^{-\la(m+h+o(1))}. 
\end{equation*}
On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
    J_\la\le e^{-\la m}\,\si(\S^{d-1})=e^{-\la(m+o(1))}. 
\end{equation*}
Since $h>0$ is arbitrary, \eqref{1} follows.

Comment: Keep in mind $\lambda o(1)$ could be anything. One should do a Laplace method argument to get a true asymptotic estimate. Finding the minima with Lagrange multipliers should be easy.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam : (i) $\lambda o(1)$ cannot be anything -- it is, of course, $o(\lambda)$. (ii) Of course, one can find the asymptotic of $J_\lambda$ itself, rather than of $\ln J_\lambda$ -- as was done. However, the asymptotic expression for $J_\lambda$  will be very messy, with probably only implicit expressions for certain involved eigenvalues. Even the expressions for the minimum $m$ of $s(x)$ will be messy if more than one of the $k_j$'s equals $2$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Overall, such a derivation will probably be much longer than a typical MO answer. According to what I have only done in my head, the asymptotic expression for $J_\lambda$ will be of the form $C\lambda^{-p}e^{-m\lambda}$, where $C\in(0,\infty)$ depends only on $d$ and the $k_j$, and $p=(d-1-\max(0,r-1))/2$, where in turn $r:=\#\{j\colon k_j=2\}$.

Comment: You're right, it's more messy than I thought.